# Which is better for a Spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm creating a Spinner using an array inside `strings.xml`.

I notice that I can use `android:entries="@array/theName"` to populate my spinner. 
Or I can use this code:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.theName, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

So what's the difference between these two? Does one run faster then the other. I'm all for not using all the code but if its going to cause problem with the rest of my app I would rather use the code. I'm planning on taking what a user selected and using it else where in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are valid.

If you have already the string array into your res folder, go with the XML code. It's simpler and cleaner.
Otherwise if you get your array dynamically (from internet for instance), use the java approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little difference between these to approaches, the attribute `android:entries` is primarily a convenience method. You can see the code for yourself:

1. [ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.createFromResource%28android.content.Context%2Cint%2Cint%29)
2. Using [`android:entries`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/AbsSpinner.java#AbsSpinner.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.util.AttributeSet%2Cint%29)

They both call `Resources.getTextArray()` and create an `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>`. The main difference is that: using method 1 allows you to use custom layouts, while using method 2 only requires one line of XML code.

To quote the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AbsSpinner_entries) on the attribute `entries`:

> For static content, this is simpler than populating the Spinner programmatically.